# How to groupby three columns in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, group-by

I have a scenario where first I need to group by unique `movie_id` and `session_id` then I need to group them by date [created_at].
So if I have this db structure:

`movie_id | session_id | created_at`
  `1      |     1      | 2021-05-11 16:02:41` 
  `2      |     1      | 2021-05-12 16:02:41` 
  `1      |     1      | 2021-05-11 16:02:41` 
  `1      |     1      | 2021-05-12 16:02:41`

I need output like this:

```
[{
    "date": "2021-05-11",
    "users": 1
},
{
    "date": "2021-05-12",
    "users": 2
}]
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$result = Activities::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])
        ->groupBy(['session_id', 'movie_id', 'date'])    
        ->get(array(
            DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "views"'),
        ));
```

But it is returning this:

```
[{
    "date": "2021-05-11",
    "views": 2
},
{
    "date": "2021-05-12",
    "views": 1
},
{
    "date": "2021-05-12",
    "views": 1
}]
```

I believe that groupBy date is not working. Can someone suggest any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i implemented group by on column **movie_id** and **session_id** and then apply group by on **date** as below :

```
$result = Activities::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])
            ->groupBy(['session_id', 'movie_id'])    
            ->get(array(
                DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "views"'),
            ));

        $result = $result->groupBy('date');
```

Comment: Its not giving the required result.